# Deploying a blazor server side

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I need to deploy a blazor server side web application written in .net code 3.1. What files do I need to include in the deployment?
Do I include only the dll files, the appsetting, and the .exe contained in the bin\release\netcoreapp3.1\ or every file including .razor, _Host.cshtml, _Import.razor, and what is in Shared\MainLayout.razor etc?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the docs on publishing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: It's very generic, doesn't mention the blazor pages

Comment: If you run `dotnet publish`, you should get a folder with everything you need to deploy.

Comment: Publish applies to all dotnet project types, not just Blazor.  If you want some additional Blazor-specific deployment advice, this may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: This higher-level link may also help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio